# Azure Stream Analytics cannot see event hubs in same subscription

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I created an Event Hub and have working code producing and consuming events from the hub, however, I went to go add a Streaming Analytics Job but the Add Input dialog cannot see my namespace when the "use event hub from current subscription" option is selected.  They are all in the same subscription(the only one I have) and I am the admin and my user account is owner on the event hub.  Why can't the portal blade 'see' my event hub namespace and hub? They are in the same Resource Group/Location too.

Anyone seen that before? I must be missing something somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is related to the fact that currently, they are separating event hub from the service bus so that it avialable in the new portal. A workaround manually enter the event hub information

Answer (score 1):

I tried to test what you said, and the result as below.

There are two types of Event Hubs which I can see on Azure new portal, as the figure below.

[image]

The `PREVIEW` one is new on Azure new portal, which instances created that could be retrieved in the add dialog of ASA Input, even could be retrieved on the EventHubs tab of Azure management portal.

The second one is classic both on Azure new portal and management portal. If you click the second one on Azure new portal, the page will be redirect to Event Hubs tab on Azure management portal. And all Event Hubs created on Azure management portal, which namespace name could be retrieved on Azure new portal, but eventhub name not. However, as @GeoffreySamper said, you can manuall type the information of EventHub created on management portal that works by my test.